# Node js обработка Post-данных

Tags: node.js, json

Здравствуйте! Проблема в следующем: на лок машине передаю данные с клиентской части в серверную. Формат примерно следующий: [ { ключ: 'знач', ключ: 'знач' }]. Дальше необходимы преобразования и манипуляция в этими данными. Но как обратиться к полученным значениям - не знаю. Все что получается - это вывести в терминале req.body. Как обратиться и собственно взять значения из переданных данных?

Comment: @Dream_TTI - ну так на прямую к полям и обращайтесь.

    req.body.key1

Если в req.body лежит строка, то преобразуйте её в объект.

Comment: В том вся и проблема, что не удается взять значение по ключу. Выдает значение undefined

Comment: @Dream_TTI - Если вы сделаете console.log(req.body); - что выведется на экран?

Comment: @ua6xh все выводится как надо, то есть то, что я и отправляю. Прикрепил выше для наглядности

Comment: Сделайте так:

    var body = JSON.parse(req.body);
    console.log("key1:" + body[0].id);

Comment: @ua6xh Unexpected token o at Object.parse (native)

Comment: @Dream_TTI - ну, на этом заканчиваются мои телекинетические способности.
Код коллбека в студию.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654733/jsonnode-js-unexpected-token-o - тут уже все написанно. это объект и его не надо привидить к объекту. Но и toString() не помогает. Выдает значение undefined
var body = toString(req.body);
console.log("key1:" + body);
выдает следующее: 
key1:[object Undefined]